# mysql how to make comments table for 2 different tables

Tags: mysql

In my DB i have 2 different tables (one for Articles that users post and one for live games). Is it possible to make comments table for these 2 articles and live games tables or i need comments table for each of them

Comment: it is possible to have a single comments table. just add a column called `related_table` where you either have `comment` or `live_game`

Answer (score 0):

Sure, why not. You just need a table that will have two referencing columns: one will reference `articles` and one will reference `games`. Both columns may be `NULL`, so you may use it either way.

```
CREATE TABLE comments (
    id int auto_increment NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    article_id int,
    game_id int,
    created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    created_by varchar NOT NULL,
    val text NOT NULL
);
```